# Error:(67, 45) error: incompatible types: View cannot be converted to TextView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

So i am trying this tutorial on android with recyclerview's cardview through this tutorial 
[Android RecyclerView and CardView Tutorial](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-recyclerview-cardview-tutorial/)
 All is well when i recreated it in an seperated test application and it runs smoothly, but when i tried it to implement it in my main project it started produce this error. thanks in advance

---

> Error:(67, 45) error: incompatible types: View cannot be converted to TextView

in the Customer Adapter

```
    class PostViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView textname, textbody, textdate;
    ImageView imageAvatar;

        public PostViewHolder(View itemView)
        {
                super(itemView);

->these lines            textname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textname);
           textbody = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textbody);
           textdate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textdate);
           imageAvatar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageAvatar); <-

        }
 }
```

Comment: First check do you inflating real layout. Then if you do check inside the layout did you declare right `views`. Maybe you declare something else instead of `TextView`

Comment: i did all that and but same error :( but thanks for the comment.

Comment: I don't believe that your issue is caused by the `Android Studio` version. I don't cast views in `ViewHolder`. I'm almost 100% sure your issue is either in `adapter` class or in `layout`.

Answer (score 7):

Just cast them to **`TextView`**

```
textname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textname);
textbody = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textbody);
textdate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textdate);
imageAvatar = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageAvatar);
```

Comment: does android compiledSdkVersion has something to do with that problem? cause my main project was in in version 25, and the tutorial has 26?

Comment: No, the reason of the problem is that probably the guy doing the tutorial was using android studio 3.0, and in that version you dont have to cast views anymore.

Comment: actually im fully up to date and im using 3.0 too soo i dont think that thats my problem

Comment: It appears that it has to do with the compileSdkVersion also, it has to be at least 26 for the casts to not to be necessary

Comment: Turns out that in 3.0 are no longer necessary because it creates all projects with 26